# Plotlyを用いた上下段のグラフの作成

Tags: python, plotly-python

上下の2段にグラフを表示させたいのですが、下段のグラフのところで"fig.update_layout(...)"を追加すると、上段のグラフが消えてしまいます。
こちらの対処方法につきご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.subplots as sp

# データの準備
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y1 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 4, 2])
y2 = np.array([2, 4, 3, 1, 5])
y3 = np.array([6, 4, 2, 5, 3])

# 上段のグラフ
fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.05)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='lines+markers', name='y1'), row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='y1', range=[0, 7], row=1, col=1)


# 下段のグラフ
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='lines+markers', name='y2', yaxis = "y2"), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y3, name='y3'), row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title='y2',overlaying='y2', side = 'left'), yaxis2=dict(title='y3', side='right'))


# グラフの表示
fig.update_layout(title='2段グラフ', height=600)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title='y2',overlaying='y2', side = 'left'), yaxis2=dict(title='y3', side='right'))
```

の`,overlaying='y2'`を削除し、次のように変更すれば２つのグラフが上下に表示されます。

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title='y2', side = 'left'), yaxis2=dict(title='y3', side='right'))
```

引数の`overlaying`は指定した軸(この場合`y2`)に重ねたいときに使うもののようです。